# Build an array of 2 or 3 fields in each record

Tags: php, arrays, field

I'm trying to build a simple array of multiple fields in each record (or item),
such as a table of (name,sex,id, etc)   or (surname, name, phone-no)  etc
In this case, I'd like to store the filename, filesize (and optionally filedate,etc) of each entry in a directory.
One field in each record is easy. But how do I store multiple fields in the array for later accessing?

What I have so far:

```
$dir= "xxxxen/";        <!-- Select Language folder  -->     
$myDirectory = opendir($dir);     
$dirarray = array();     
// get each entry     
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {      
   if ($entryName != "." && $entryName != "..") {    
      $entrySize = filesize($dir  .$entryName);      
      echo $entryName . ' --- ' . $entrySize . ' bytes<br/>';     
      $dirArray[] = $entryName;  ====AND???? ====     
   }     
}     
// close directory
```

Now, how do I save the file size in this array?
Hopefully, I'm just missing some syntax in the **"AND???"** above.
Perhaps I'm using the wrong search arguments, but there are precious few examples of this (actually none), including searching php.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try using an Associative Array;
Something like this

```
$dirArray[] = array("name" => $entryName, "entrySize" => $entrySize);
```

Latter you can access the value with this:

```
echo $dirArray[0]["name"];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you can take a look at this post: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest a re-write...

If you use `chdir()` to assign the targeted folder as the current working directory, you can call `glob()` with no path included.  The output array from `glob()` will not include `.` and `..`.  This makes the snippet very concise.

Code:

```
chdir("xxxxen");
foreach (glob("*") as $file) {
    $result[] = ['filename' => $file, 'filesize' => filesize($file)];
}     
var_export($result);
```

On my dummy/test directory, this is the output:

```
array (
    0 => array ( 'filename' => 'ex1_1.png', 'filesize' => 165083, ),
    1 => array ( 'filename' => 'ex1_2.png', 'filesize' => 3596235, ),
    2 => array ( 'filename' => 'ex2_1.png', 'filesize' => 1098743, )
)
```

So, then obviously, you can iterate this multi-dimensional array to access what you need "down script".

Comment: I noticed the "glob" before, but this wasn't my original problem.
BUT-  can I use glob to select only *.php AND *.htm in a folder?

Comment: It is an easy adjustment: `foreach (glob("*.{php,htm}",GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {`

Answer (score 0):

use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) inside your `while` loop, something like this

```
$dir= "xxxxen/";        
$myDirectory = opendir($dir);     
$dirarray = array();     
// get each entry     
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {      
   if ($entryName != "." && $entryName != ".."):
      array_push($dirarray,array(
          "entrySize"=>filesize($dir . $entryName),
          "entryName"=>$entryName . ' --- ' . $entrySize . ' bytes'
      ));
   endif;
}
```

Comment: Aside from syntax, what the diff between array_push  and $dirarray[] = array(...)  ?      
Fewer machine cycles? less coding?

Comment: @aqk i think there is no difference, imo in pushing many entries to the array it is more efficient

Comment: @aqk `array_push()` is a function call when a function call is not necessary. `$dirarray[] = ...` does the same thing with less effort.  `array_push()` isn't going to be more efficient, but unless you are doing LOTS of files, no one will notice the impact.

Comment: Yeah- I like to keep things simple-  "if" and "while" are easily understood in most languages, whereas (I assume) array-push and glob are unique to PHP. If I don't look again at this code for 2-3 yrs, I will then wonder "wtf is this? What was I doing there??"   .. I'm not a PHP programer.  ;-)